# Do I need to explicitly release extension licenses?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-license-manager

I'm writing an application using ArcObjects. I initialize the license with code similar to this:

```
var extensionCodes = new[] {
    esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeNetwork,
    esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSpatialAnalyst
};

lic = new AoInitialize();
lic.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced)
foreach (var ext in extensionCodes) {
    lic.CheckOutExtension(ext);
}
```

(I have more result checking and error handling in my actual code, as well as a pre-check for availability.)

All the samples and documentation I can find say to use `Shutdown` to release the licenses:

```
lic.Shutdown();
```

But none of the examples I could find used extensions. Is `Shutdown` enough to release them back to the license server, or do I need to check those back in explicitly like so:

```
foreach (var ext in extensionCodes) {
    lic.CheckInExtension(ext);
}
```

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1 currently, but I would like to know if previous versions are known to be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [help docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/CheckInExtension_Method/00420000006v000000/), it is probably safest to do **both** by explicitly checking the license in with the extension code and then calling `lic.Shutdown()` depending on how you're checking out the license.  From the help:

> The way that the extensions are checked in and out will depend on the
>   type of product license passed to the Initialize method.
>
> If the application was initialized with either of the Engine Single Use licenses, any extensions used by the application will also
>   be Engine Single Use. As such any extensions can be checked out
>   directly after the application is initialized and checked back in
>   before Shutdown.
>
> If the application was initialized with a license server and the extensions are required by the application for it to run successfully,
>   the extensions should be checked out directly after the application is
>   initialized and checked back in before Shutdown.
>
> If the application was initialized with a license server and the extension functionality 
>   is not necessary for the application to
>   function, the extensions can either be checked out directly after the
>   application is initialized or checked out as and when the extension
>   functionality is required. When the extension is checked in the
>   functionality should be disabled. Use the IsExtensionCheckedOut method
>   determines whether the extension is already checked out.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like a pretty definitive, "Yes, I need to check them in explicitly," to me. I wasn't able to find that documentation. Btw, your link has an extra `%20http://` that makes it not directly clickable.